# flask - url with searched word

Tags: python, flask

I want to ask how to make my urls to include the worh that I searched. Something like this:

```
http://host/filter?test
```

My code:

```
    @app.route('/filter', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def filter():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if str(request.form['search_string']) <> '':
                api.queryMessage(request.form['search_string'])
       return render_template('main.html', search_string=search_string)
```

And my template, main.html:

```
<form name="filters" action="{{ url_for('filter') }}" method=post id="filters">
   <div style="position: absolute; top:100px; left:300px">
       <p>Search string: <input type=text size=80 title="Match all of the words"   name=search_string value="{{search_string}}"></p>
       <input type=submit value=Filter/Search onclick=loopSelected();>
       <input type="hidden" name="chosen" id="chosen" value="{{chosen}}" />
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're now using POST request. Use GET request, so browser will put your form values to URL.

in HTML form set method="GET":

```
<form name="filters" action="{{ url_for('filter') }}" method="GET" id="filters">
```

You'll get URL in the following form:

```
http://host/filter?search_string=test&chosen=<id>&<some other trash>
```

In Flask use request.args instead of request.form:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    if request.args.get('search_string'):
        ...
```